# .git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, commit

Opa, estou trabalhando um repositório faz um tempo e hoje ocorreu o seguinte erro ao tentar commitar:

```
Erro: Unable to create 'C:/MyProject/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an editor 
opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then
 try again. If it still fails, a git process may have crashed in this 
repository earlier: remove the file manually to continue.
```

[Imagem com o erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9mGU.png)

Busquei em diversos blogs uma resposta e em todas a solução é excluir o arquivo "index.lock", porém ele não existe no meu diretório do git:

[Diretório do git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELE7o.png)

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer para resolver?

Comment: da uma olhanda na subpasta ".git\refs\heads", veja se tem algum outro arquivo ".lock" com o nome da branch e tenta deletar

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: @RicardoPontual , procurei em todos os diretórios da pasta e não existe um arquivo ".lock", é isso o que mais me intriga